# Xcode 4.5.x Version Editor shows "No Editor" Message

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control

I recently started a new project with nothing unusual about it.  Whenever I go to use the Version Editor I get the message "No Editor" where the text normally would appear.  Even stranger, this is the same for all my files except for the Project itself.  It actually shows version history properly.

The only thing I've done differently with this project from any others is use Cocos2D and BitBucket (with GIT).  Everything else is pretty vanilla.

Answer (score 1):

You should select file and wait for long time. 
Sometimes I have same issue with project file. After 3-5 minutes the issue was fixed (editor was loaded) and I can edit the conflict.

Comment: this is probably because of large amount of files in project. thanks for the hint, saved my day)

Answer (score 0):

The Version Editor has always been pretty buggy.

Try `File -> Source Control -> Refresh Status` and see if it fixes it.